# How to use arithmetic operations for visual basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, operators, math, currency

How do you use money in visual basic I know that I have to set nickels and divide by 5 and I am suppose to have another expression to the number. Then i am suppose to determine what change i would have left so that way i can determine how many pennies I have. Thanks to all who looks.

```
Dim change As Integer
Dim amountused As Integer
Dim quarters As Integer
Dim dimes As Integer
Dim nickels As Integer
Dim pennies As Integer
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your amount here")
amountused = Console.ReadLine()
Console.WriteLine("change= 100-amount used")
Console.WriteLine(quarters = change \ 25)
Console.WriteLine(dimes = (change - quarters * 25) / 10)
Console.WriteLine(nickels = change \ 5)
Console.WriteLine(pennies =
```

edit:Can someone hint to me what I am doing wrong I don't get nothing for output Thanks... The hint could be example check this line. Thanks

```
    Dim change As Integer
    Dim amountused As Integer
    Dim quarters As Integer
    Dim dimes As Integer
    Dim nickels As Integer
    Dim pennies As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your amount here")
    amountused = Console.ReadLine()
    change = ("100 - amountused")
    quarters = change \ 25
    Console.WriteLine("Quarters:{0}", quarters)
    change = change - (quarters * 25)
    dimes = change \ 10
    Console.WriteLine("Dimes: {0}", quarters)
    change = change - (dimes * 10)
    nickels = change \ 5
    change = change - (nickels * 5)
    Console.WriteLine("nickels: {0}", quarters)
    change = pennies \ 1
    change = change - (pennies * 1)
    Console.WriteLine("pennies:{0}", pennies)
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding change, I would suggest you actually use [`Math.DivRem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yda5c8dx.aspx) which will answer both the relevant questions at once:

- How many of this coin can I use?
- How much will I still left to deal with afterwards?

EDIT: If you really want to stick to arithmetic, I'd keep a count of how much you still need to use up. For example:

```
quarters = change \ 25
Console.WriteLine("Quarters: {0}", quarters)
change = change - (quarters * 25)

dimes = change \ 10
Console.WriteLine("Dimes: {0}", quarters)
change = change - (dimes * 10)
... etc
```

That way you don't need to keep worrying about your previous results.

Comment: I haven't made it to use the Math.divRem.

Comment: @sha: sorry, I don't understand your comment. Could you try again?

Comment: i have no used the math.divrem i just started using visual basic so i am still a beginner.I know that I am suppose to use the arithmetic operators but i dont know which one will work for this.

Comment: i am suppose to ask the user to enter in amount less than $1.00 and calculate the change from the $1.00 output the change along with how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.

Comment: @sha: Following the link will take you to the documentation for Math.DivRem. However, I'll edit the answer to give you some other hints.

Comment: ok thank you So now with the pennies since pennies is one 1 cent is that all i put too

Comment: @sha: Yes, when you've got down to pennies, that will just be equal to "change" at that point.